# R programming - read a table

Tags: r, read.table

I have one problem when I want to read a table from txt file in R.
When I do

```
dat <- read.table("~/data/data.txt", quote="\""),
```

it is working perfectly. But, when I try to name the colums with this commands :

```
dat <- read.table("~/data/data.txt",quote="\"",c("com","Type","blabla","blabla"),header=TRUE).
```

I have this error :

```
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  :   invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're passing column names to the `sep` argument. Unless you name arguments, you need to pass them in order. See `?read.table`. Try `read.table("~/data/data.txt", quote="\"", col.names=c("com","Type","blabla","blabla"), header=TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename the columns, just add `col.names =` before your vector of names.

You therefore have something like:

```
dat <- read.table("~/data/data.txt", quote="\"", 
                  col.names=c("com", "Type", "blabla", "blabla"), header=TRUE).
```

This might solve your problem.